# How do I move an l-value to a function implicitly, with no explicit call to std::move()?

Tags: c++, c++17, move, syntactic-sugar

I have a movable, but not copyable, class `Service`, another class `Collection` and a function `Collection::Attach()` which should take an object of type `Service` as an argument.

The context makes it clear that collection object takes ownership of all attached services, and that once attached the service must not be used directly any more. Which naturally translates to moving a service object to the collection, and suggests that `Collection::Attach()` should be declared like

```
void Attach(Service);
```

But then, I anticipate the following use cases marked (1) and (2):

```
#include <utility>

struct Service
{
    Service() = default;
    Service(Service&&) = default;       // Move ok.
    Service(const Service&) = delete;   // No copy.
};

struct Collection
{
    // How do I declare this method so that
    // use cases (1) and (2) shown below both work?
    void Attach(Service);
};

void foo(Collection* collection)
{
    // This works fine:
    collection->Attach(Service{});            // (1)
}

void bar(Collection* collection)
{
    Service      s;

    // This works fine but 'std::move()' seems redundant:
    collection->Attach(std::move(s));

    // I want the following line to work
    // asif 'std::move()' was there:
    collection->Attach(s);                   // (2)
}
```

and I would very much like to lift the burden of typing `std::move()` in use case (2) off client programmers. Again, the context and names make it clear that the argument is moved.

The question:
**Can I do this without overloading `Attach()`?**

```
void Attach(Service&&);
void Attach(Service&);
```

because that looks ugly to me.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. You want to make the copy constructor that semantically behaves like move constructor (why?), but without defining a copy constructor (huh?)?

Comment: @Brian, No, I want to declare 'Attach()' method in a way so that it would implicitly move its argument, whether that argument is a temporary object or an lvalue.

Comment: Implicitly move is very bug-prone and such sneaky modification often results in unexpected behavior, so I strongly recommend that you should use `std::move` for explicit moves.

Comment: Move semantics are intentionally designed so that this is not possible. You can circumvent it by making an unconventional copy constructor behave like a move constructor, but that will cause expectations of basically all standard library and other libraries to be violated if the type is used with them, potentially causing very subtle bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ƴou could define a non-const-taking copy constructor and make that actually move-construct:

```cpp
struct Service
{
  Service(Service& other){
    // move-construct from other.
  }
};
```

But note that that is a very bad idea.

Otherwise you will have to overload `Attach` to also take a `Service&` and move out of the passed-in reference. Which is also a bad idea, but less bad than the previous one.

You already know what do to and implemented it correctly. No, `std::move` does not look pretty and C++ would probably be better off if move semantics where the default. But they're not. If you want that, take a look at Rust.

> The context makes it clear that collection object takes ownership of all attached services, and that once attached the service must not be used directly any more.

I highly doubt that "the context" makes that clear – if I didn't move my object away (via `std::move`), I will assume that I can still access it.

Comment: I second this. Or, I would take it even further: if the function is a sink, rvalue reference is a way to go due to API clarity. auto_ptr was disliked for a multitude of reasons and that weird moving-copy semantics was one of them.